# AVPlayer Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Ok so in my iOS app there is a screen with an AVPlayerViewController that takes care of playing videos. When this video is played it fills the entire screen however on some videos they video seems stretched as if it is being forced to fit. Is there any way to make the video fit the entire screen without losing the aspect ratio.

The code below is what I use to lay out the AVPlayerController. I figured some error here is the cause of this flaw in aspect ratio.

```
/

// Setup the view for stories
    private func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        // Setup the blur view for loading
        blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: view.frame)
        blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)

        self.view.addSubview(blurView)

        // Indicator for loading
        let indicatorFrame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 20, y: view.center.y - 20, width: 40, height: 40)
        indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: indicatorFrame)
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge

        blurView.contentView.addSubview(indicator)

        // Setup the Progress bar
//        spb = SegmentedProgressBar(numberOfSegments: allStories.count)
////        spb.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 1, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 9)
//        self.view.addSubview(spb)
//        spb.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
//            make.left.right.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
//            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(1)
//            make.height.equalTo(9)
//        }
//
//        spb.delegate = self

        // Player Controller
        playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false

        self.addChildViewController(playerController)

        // Image view for the story
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)

        infoView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        infoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        // The image view for the user of the current story
        infoImageView = UIImageView()
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
//        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: spb)

        self.view.addSubview(infoView)

        self.infoView.addSubview(infoImageView)

        infoImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(2)
            make.left.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.left).offset(10)
            make.height.width.equalTo(30)
        }
        infoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        infoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        // The name for the user of the current story
        infoNameLabel = UILabel()
        infoNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        infoNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        infoNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        infoNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        self.infoView.addSubview(infoNameLabel)

        infoNameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(infoImageView.snp.right).offset(5)
            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(2)
            make.height.equalTo(30)
            make.width.equalTo(80)
        }

        // Time label for long ago the story was posted
        infoTimeLabel = UILabel()
        infoTimeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        infoTimeLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

        self.infoView.addSubview(infoTimeLabel)

        infoTimeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(infoNameLabel.snp.right).offset(5)
            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(2)
            make.height.equalTo(30)
            make.width.equalTo(50)
        }

        infoView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        infoView.addGestureRecognizer(tapInfoView)
        infoView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeInfoView)

        infoTimeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        infoTimeLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        infoTimeLabel.textAlignment = .center

        infoNameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        infoNameLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        infoNameLabel.textAlignment = .center

        playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
        playerController.view.frame = view.frame

//        spb.durations = durations
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

to keep the video aspect ratio in the defined view frame use
`AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect`.
 For the current case replace
`playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue`
to
`playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about it but use this :

```
playerController.view.frame = view.bounds
```

Instead of this:

```
playerController.view.frame = view.frame
```

The `AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue` should do what is says and I never had a problem with it. However, I use the bounds instead of the frame and I remember getting problem when using the frame.

You also have `AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect.rawValue` that will fit the video instead of filling it.

You can also try setting the frame before the video gravity.

Comment: i will try this now